# ESLint no-undef rule: many of functions in another file

Tags: javascript, eslint

The question is about.. how to tell eslint not to show error if the function is in another file?
Example:
--- core.js --- some core code without utils definitions

```
function draw() {
  const color = getRandomColor();
  canvasClear();
  drawNode();
  drawLevel();
  drawLine();
  drawCaption();
}
```

--- draw-utils.js --- function declarations

```
function getRandomColor() {...};
function canvasClear() {...};
function drawNode() {...};
function drawLevel() {...};
function drawLine() {...};
function drawCaption() {...};
```

Of course there are many of eslint 'no-undef' errors, because there is no all of this functions's declarations. The second file is also full of 'no-unused-vars'.

Is there a way to tell them about themselves? **Without** 'globals' section in .eslint.json

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use some kind of module system rather than relying on stuff being in the global scope.

Comment: Of course modules are great, but if understand correct, there is no modules native support in browsers.. so I need to use module bundlers like webpack to get one source-bundle.js
But the problem I've tried to solve is to separate one file to several files. And eslint annoys me.

Comment: Your information is out of date. Native modules are [supported in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility) with > [7% global market share](https://www.statista.com/statistics/544400/market-share-of-internet-browsers-desktop/). Have been for a bit now. And eslint is configurable for that very reason.

Comment: @JaredSmith mmm.. I'll think about it.. i've tried modules in last google chrome about 2 weeks ago and just got unworking project :) need for more tests

Comment: I'm not trying to paint a rosier picture than exists. I've been using native modules, in production, for over a year (I don't have to support oddball browsers often, 80% of my projects are internal and not public facing). The only problem is third-party integration: most libraries are, if you're lucky, written for webpack (not compatible with current native implementations) or if you're not lucky common js. Very few libraries play nice with native modules.

Comment: Anyways, all of this is somewhat academic. The bottom line is that dumping everything into the global scope with absolutely no encapsulation (not even the old school revealing module design pattern) is a way bigger problem than anything else that a linter might catch. Which is why your linter is not configured to work properly when dumping everything into the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef). Add a `globals` section to the JS file itself.

> ```
> /*global someFunction b:true*/
> /*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
>
> var a = someFunction();
> b = 10;
> ```

Comment: So I need to contaminate my js-file head instead os .eslintrc.json contamination? It seems to be not so good idea, I think.

Comment: @Nick_Rimer — You have to declare them *somewhere*, and it either has to be in the configuration for all JS files, in the configuration for *this* JS file, or by using a module system. The linter can't magic up the difference between a variable declared in another file and one that just has the wrong name.

Comment: Wanna ask why there is just no functionality to list file paths to search declarations in, but of course it is a question to eslint developers, not for you..

Comment: @Nick_Rimer whenever you find that something that seems like it should exist does not, in fact, exist, you have either found a tremendous opportunity or a hole in your understanding. Either way it's good for you.